# Code Coverage Analysis: Failed to enable constraints

Tags: visual-studio, code-coverage

I am having a problem of opening a code coverage (.coverage) file that is generated by MSBuild in TFS. I cannot track down the actual cause. I can assure there are no duplicate test namings. We are using MSTest and xUnit tests in the solution. The error is as follows:

> **CodeCoverageInfoProvider.InitAnalysisEngine**: Exception occurred: Code
>   Coverage Analysis engine threw exception(s): Failed to enable
>   constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null,
>   unique, or foreign-key constraints.

I use visual studio 2015 Enterprise with update 3 alongside TFS 2015.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: I do not think this is the right observation - TFS is generating (using codecoverage component to generate) that file and it might be a bug in there. VS just fails to open a malformed file, or vs fails due to it's bug to open a proper file. If you know that it is definitely not TFS, please let me know.

Comment: Do you have other code coverage files that can be opened before? We can do a swap test. You can try on another machine to open the new generated code coverage file to see whether is can be opened. If you have other code coverage file, you can try to open it on your machine. Then we can tell where this issue come from.

Comment: I am also having the same issue with MSUnitets, the When I click on run all tests it runs all the tests and finally throwing an exception "Exception was thrown: Code Coverage Analysis engine threw exception(s):

Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints."